# Automatically convert Mac file path to PC file path

Tags: windows-explorer, platform-specific, platform-detection

I want to create a script that will always run in Windows Explorer that will take a Mac OS X path and convert it to a Windows path automatically.  So if I receive a Mac path and am working on Windows I can copy the Mac file path into Explorer and it will resolve to the proper location.

Example:

Mac Path: `file:///Volumes/file_server/projects/foo`
Win Path: `Z:\projects\foo`

Is there a way to add in this functionality to Windows?

Comment: Could you specify what you actually want. You haven't done so. Would a regex that converted file:///Volumes/file_server/ into Z:\ suffice?

Comment: I'm actually looking for how I can get a script or addin to run in Windows Explorer and resolve the paths correctly.  Any script language will do.  I'm capable of figuring out the regex.  I'm more trying to figure out how to extend behavior in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @jaysnop That's not going to be possible in an easy fashion I suspect.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be easy, otherwise I wouldn't be asking for help. :)

Comment: Explorer doesn't really do add-ins, to the best of my knowledge. How do you want to get this path into Explorer? Do you have any UI in mind?

Comment: copy and paste.  Someone sends me a Mac file path, I copy it and paste it in the address bar of Windows Explorer and it resolves properly.

Comment: How is an absolute file path going to resolve correctly on a complete different machine? You're leaving out some crucial bit of information here, and it probably has something to do with a network file system, given your use of 'Z' as a drive letter.

Comment: That is kind of what I am asking.  Ideally, you paste the path into the address bar, when you hit go/enter and the event triggers which will call a script that resolves the path then updates the address bar path with the corrected PC path.

Comment: Basically, I'm asking for a solution to help resolve the paths so a PC user can easily use a Mac file path, both of which are pointing to the same server.